# Facing difficulty to pass label value into listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, label, formview

What i am looking for is to get the value of " Label10 "  which is into viewmsgView and then bind the FormView1 depending on the label value, Note: viewmsgView  &  FormView1  are located into same view and in same page. But i am getting an error message as below and i have added find control because it give error message that control is not available or does not exist.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" next to line:

```
RedMsgDAADP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mailno", ((Label)myControl).Text);
```

viewmsgView  which include Label10 and as well the titlehyplink which when user click on it will show and bind FormView1

```
<asp:ListView ID="viewmsgView" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>


                        <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <table class="table table-inbox table-hover" style="width:100%; margin-left:0px;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class="unread">

                        <td>

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="deltimgbtn" runat="server" 
                                ImageUrl="~/iconsimg/Delete2.png" onclick="deltimgbtn_Click" /> </td>  <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ReplyBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/iconsimg/reply.png" 
                                onclick="ReplyBtn_Click" /></td>
                        <td class="view-message  dont-show"><asp:Label ID="msgfromlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("sender") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="view-message "><asp:LinkButton
                                ID="titlehyplink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("Mestitle") %>' onclick="titlehyplink_Click"></asp:LinkButton></td>
                        <td class="view-message  inbox-small-cells"><asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Style="color: #FFFFFF" Text='<%# Bind ("mailno") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="view-message  text-right"><asp:Label ID="datelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("Date") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr></tbody></table>
                    </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
```

FormView1  which will show message details depending on Label10 which is into viewmsgView

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server"  Width="100%">

                        <ItemTemplate>


                     <br /><br />
                     <div style="margin-bottom:40px; background-color:#CCCCCC;">
                         <div class="col-md-4">

                                        <label>From:</label>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <asp:Label ID="senderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sender") %>' />

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label>Date:</label>

                                        <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>' />
                                </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label>To:</label>

                                        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Receiver") %>' />
                                    </div>

                                     <div class="col-md-4">
                                   <label>Mail No:</label>

                                    <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("mailno") %>' />
                              </div>

                                 <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label>Ads No:</label>

                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="AdsIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AdsID") %>' />
                                  </div>

                                   </div>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="MestitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mestitle") %>' Font-Bold="True"
                                Font-Size="Larger" /><br />
                            <br />

                            <asp:Label ID="MessageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Message") %>' Width="100%"
                                CssClass="labelmsg" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:FormView>
```

titlehyplink code behind

```
protected void titlehyplink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["UsrNme"] != null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection RedMsgSQLCon = new SqlConnection(sc))
            {
                RedMsgSQLCon.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter RedMsgDAADP = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * From mails where Receiver=@UID And mailno=@mailno", sc);

                var use = Session["UsrNme"];

                Control myControl = FindControl("Label10");

                RedMsgDAADP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", use);
                RedMsgDAADP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mailno", ((Label)myControl).Text);

                DataSet RedMsgCVs = new DataSet();

                RedMsgDAADP.Fill(RedMsgCVs);

                FormView1.DataSource = RedMsgCVs.Tables[0];
                FormView1.DataBind();
                FormView1.Visible = true;
            }

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label10 control is a child control in viewmsgView and will be created for every row with a unique ID, you will have as many Label10 controls as the rows in viewmsgView. One way you can grab the value without much effort is changing these line:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="titlehyplink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("Mestitle") %>' onclick="titlehyplink_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

into this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="titlehyplink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind "Mestitle") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Bind ("mailno") %>' OnCommand="titlehyplink_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and then on your code change

```
protected void titlehyplink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

to

```
protected void titlehyplink_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
```

and in that method you can use something like this:

```
RedMsgDAADP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mailno", e.CommandArgument);
```

Few tips:

FindControl("Label10");
only looks into the Page controls collection not child's control collection.

Id of Label10 will be generated automatically with a number added to the end of it like Label10_0 and also contains id of the parent control like viewmsgView_Label10_0, so you can't find it with just "Label10"

Comment: Hi @NET Developer , many thanks for your reply, i have did as you mention but i get this error:    "    
Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Line 1429:                                    onclick="ReplyBtn_Click" /></td>
Line 1431:                            <td class="view-message "><asp:LinkButton ID="titlehyplink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind "Mestitle") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Bind ("mailno") %>' OnCommand="titlehyplink_Command"></asp:LinkButton></td>
"